# program/application or script that reads /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, hosts

What is the name of the program or script that opens and reads /etc/hosts when name resolution is needed? and is it different for every linux/unix distro?

I read the man page for hosts and tried whereis looking for a binary named hosts but whereis outputs filenames like /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny. I was under the impression that hosts.allow and hosts.deny were config files for TCPWrappers and now Im more confused than when I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific *program* that parses this file.

A number of standard files (e.g. `/etc/hosts`) are parsed by standard library files (e.g. `gethostbyname(3)`).  However the story may be a lot more complicated.

Hostname resolution is typically controlled by an entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

e.g.

```
% grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:      files dns
```

This entry tells the resolver routines to use the "files" backend, and if the result isn't found there then to do a DNS lookup.  Other values could be placed there (e.g. `ldap` or `nis`) which can change the way that hostnames are looked up.

These routines are typically called "Naming Services".  The same concepts are also used for username lookups (`passwd`), group entries (`group`) and so on.

So when you do `ping a.remote.host` then the `ping` program will call a glibc library function, and that will load the routines defined in `nsswitch.conf`.  The result is you won't see a specific program to do the lookup; `ping` does the work itself, via the libary and NS routines.

There's a program called `getent` that can be used to do the name searching; you specify a "database" (one of the entries in `nsswitch.conf`) and the value you want to search for.

So

```
getent hosts a.remote.host
```

will do a name lookup following the rules defined in `nsswitch.conf`.  This is useful for testing purposes, and sometimes also in scripts.

--- addendum ----

This information is from Stephen's comment below, but very useful, so I am adding it to his answer.

```
strace getent hosts www.google.com 2>&1 | grep libnss_
```

will tell which library (or none) was used to resolve the name. If it says `libnss_files`, then `/etc/hosts` was used. If it says `libnss_dns`, then DNS was used. `libnss_myhostname` means that nothing worked, and a backup GNU system kicked it (and may have failed). If no library is listed, then you probably used a numerical address, like `127.0.0.1`, so no resolver was necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to log what source was used from nsswitch.conf? Example- if /etc/nsswitch.conf listed - hosts: files dns ldap, and the resolver routine found the host's entry in files instead of dns. Is there a way to produce a log message that would look similar to a DNS request log or is there already a log produced that I am unaware of?

Comment: If you're trying to debug a specific lookup then `strace getent ...` is easiest.  eg `% strace getent hosts www.google.com 2>&1 | grep nss_
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3`  -- this tells me that `dns` was the last NSS module loaded and so was the last entry used.    However `% strace getent hosts localhost 2>&1 | grep nss_     
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3` only uses `files` so the name was resolved from `/etc/hosts`

Comment: The intent was to find the source code that I could modify that would allow /etc/hosts to have functionality similar to TCPWrappers (spawn and twist). So if a specific host in the hosts file is used, send a log to syslog. Something like...

Comment: 172.217.11.78    google.com   gmail : spawn (/bin/echo %a from %h accessed %d >>  /var/log/connections.log)

Comment: So the library routine that parses `/etc/hosts` is `nss_files` (eg` /usr/lib64/libnss_files.so.2` or `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2`).  The source is part of `glibc`.  You could _try_ modifying and compiling that... but it'll not be simple!

Comment: I wasnt expecting it to be easy. I just started learning C and I was always told to learn a language you just need to write code in that language. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux systems, `/etc/hosts` is typically read by `glibc` libraries.

See [GNU’s documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Names.html) on the subject:

> Internally, the system uses a database to keep track of the mapping
>   between host names and host numbers. This database is usually either
>   the file /etc/hosts or an equivalent provided by a name server. The
>   functions and other symbols for accessing this database are declared
>   in netdb.h. They are BSD features, defined unconditionally if you
>   include netdb.h.

All POSIX compliant UNIX and UNIX-like systems will follow this guideline, as netdb.h is a [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netdb.h.html). The main difference being the C library they use, as not all UNIX systems use `glibc`.

The GNU documentation also talks about functions such as `gethostbyname` and `gethostbyaddr` that read through the data gathered from `/etc/hosts`. These two functions are actually obsolete today. [`getaddrinfo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) and [`getnameinfo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getnameinfo.html) should be used instead.

Comment: To clarify, if I only care about name resolution (and not reverse look-ups) there are 3 c functions that could possibly read the /etc/hosts file (or name server equivalent)?

Comment: @python_nube: See my latest edit. I learned the functions I originally specified are now obsolete. There are two main functions for getting data from `/etc/hosts`. Those being `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo`.